# how to change the object in collection to [] with conditional

Tags: arrays, laravel, api, collections, null

I have the collection below

```
[
    {
        "versions": [
            {
                "id": null,
                "name": null,
                "price": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

but I want if id,name, price null versions set to be [] like:

```
[
    {
        "versions": [   
        ]
    }
]
```

so anyone can help me to do this? I have searched for many solutions on the internet but no one works!! tks guys!!!

Answer (score 1):

```php
$filtered = $collection->filter(function ($value, $key) {
    return $value != null;
});
```

Comment: but in collection i also have "productName" like
[{
"productName": abc,
"version":[{
"id":null,
"name":null,
"price":null,
}]
}]
so how can i access to the versions id to check if it null it change to be []